# Reflection coefficient phase using Kramers Kronig, formula equivalence

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, reflection, optical-materials

Why are the following two formulas for the phase of the reflection coefficient equivalent (according e.g. to [1])?

\begin{align}
\Theta(\omega_0) & = - \frac{\omega_0}{\pi}P\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln R(\omega)}{\omega^2 - \omega_0^2} d\omega
\\
\Theta(\omega_0) & = - \frac{\omega_0}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln( R(\omega)/R(\omega_0))}{\omega^2 - \omega_0^2} d\omega
\end{align}

My feeling is that the proof probably involves subtracting out the singularity, but I haven't been able to reach the conclusion that the formulas are equivalent using that approach.

1. Nilsson, P. O.; Munkby, L.; Investigation of errors in the Kramers-Kronig analysis of reflectance data. [*Phys. Kondens. Mater.* **10**, 290 (1969)](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02422649).